# How to prevent raw html code from being printed in my output file

Tags: html, r, quarto, glossary

I'm trying to create a website using quarto and R (Rstudio).

I'm trying to create a glossary using the [glossary](https://debruine.github.io/glossary/articles/glossary.html) package. I am able to create the table, but each table also output the raw html information (s. image)
[image: html]

I have treid to add some filtering to my yml header of the quarto file:

```
...
format: 
  html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 4
    toc-expand: true
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 4
    code-fold: true
    strip-comments: true
    from: 'markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks'
filters:
  - parse-latex
  - code-visibility
execute: 
  echo: false
...
```

But I can't make it disappear. Any ideas if this is possible at all?

thanks

Assa

**Edit**:
As requested, I'm adding here a `qmd` file to reproduce the error:

the header:

```
---
title: "Glossary"
format: 
  html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 4
    toc-expand: true
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 4
    code-fold: true
    strip-comments: true
    from: 'markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks'
filters:
  - parse-latex
  - code-visibility
execute: 
  echo: false
---
```

the R script to reproduce the problem:

```
library(glossary)

glossary_reset()
# add a definition to the table
glossary("term", def = "definition")
glossary("term 2", def = "definition 2")

glossary_table() # show table as kable
```

Comment: That looks like it'd be resolved with a chunk option (perhaps `echo=FALSE`). Please provide a reproducible Rmd doc (not just the yaml front matter) that behaves this way.

Comment: `echo: false` only make the r code disappear, but not the html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `echo=FALSE, results='asis'` to your chunk header. You also need to capture the returned value from each call to `glossary`. Options:

- capture into a variable (and no need to use it), such as `ign <- glossary(..)`
- wrap in `invisible(glossary(..))`

Here's a complete working example:

````
---
title: "Glossary"
format: 
  html:
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 4
    toc-expand: true
    number-sections: true
    number-depth: 4
    code-fold: true
    strip-comments: true
    from: 'markdown-markdown_in_html_blocks'
filters:
  - parse-latex
  - code-visibility
execute: 
  echo: false
---

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
library(glossary)

glossary_reset()
# add a definition to the table
ign <- glossary("term", def = "definition")
ign <- glossary("term 2", def = "definition 2")

glossary_table() # show table as kable
```
````

Renders as:

[image: html rendered from rmarkdown]

Comment: strange, adding the `results: asis` to the yml header for a global option only made it worse. but adding the assignment of the glossary items to a variable solved the problem, e.g. `i <- glossary(...)` (even without `results: asis`). Can't really figure out why. thanks for the suggestion that solved the problem.